# What Proof of Work does IOTA use?

Tags: proof-of-work

I have some trouble finding valid information about IOTA. Actually I would be nice if there would be a good source.

So my question is: 
Bitcoin uses the SHA-256 twice and some "target bits" for hashing it's blocks.

What PoW does IOTA use? Some sort of Hashcash Lite - but how does this work in detail?
Is there also a header with a timestamp and some previous block hash?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about [crypto currency](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

IOTA doesn't use proof of work.
IOTA is a tangle, and the consensus is reach based on the information propagation in the network. You can find more information about it here:
https://forum.iota.org/t/iota-consensus-masterclass/1193

Comment: Maybe I wasn't correct enough: You confirm two nodes of the tangle by doing a Hashcash Lite. How does this work?